# How can I get EvaluateScriptAsync() in CefSharp working?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I have a database of URLs and the screen will load 9 URLs at once like a table and load another 9 URLs after 5 minutes. I have some script to run after each ULR finished loading using the FrameLoadEnd Event Handler. I keep getting this error when the 19th URL is loading.

> unable to execute javascript at this time, scripts can only be executed within a v8context. use the iwebbrowser.canexecutejavascriptinmainframe property to guard against this exception

If there is a mistake, this error should pop up when the 1st URL is loaded but it always pops up when the 19th URL is loaded which is the third round the screen display 9 new URLs.

Here is the Code

```
wb.FrameLoadEnd += OnBrowserFrameLoadEnd;


private async void OnBrowserFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    
    ChromiumWebBrowser wb = (ChromiumWebBrowser)sender;

    await wb.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.body.style.overflow='hidden';");

    int clientHeight = 0;
    int clientWidth = 0;
    int innerHeight = 0;
    int innerWidth = 0;

    string clientRecHeightScript = @"function myFunction() {" +
                                        "var rect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();" +
                                        "ch = rect.height;" +

                                        "var rect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();" +
                                        "cw = rect.width;" +

                                        "var ih = window.innerHeight;" +

                                        "var iw = window.innerWidth;" +

                                        "const webLength = [ch, cw, ih, iw];" +

                                        "return webLength;" +
                                        "}" +
                                        "myFunction();";
                                
    await wb.EvaluateScriptAsync(clientRecHeightScript).ContinueWith(x =>  //Error occurs here
    {
        var response = x.Result;
        if (response.Result != null)
        {
            var clientRec = response.Result;
            string[] arr = ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)clientRec).Cast<object>()
                                                .Select(y => y.ToString())
                                                .ToArray();


            Int32.TryParse(arr[0], out clientHeight);
            Int32.TryParse(arr[1], out clientWidth);
            Int32.TryParse(arr[2], out innerHeight);
            Int32.TryParse(arr[3], out innerWidth);              
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any error I might have done to cause this error?

Answer (score -1):

1. Does the webpage have JavaScript on it? If not then it won't have a V8Context.
2. It's also possible the V8Context hasn't finished loading for the main frame. FrameLoadEnd is called once per frame. Sub frames may finish loading first.
3. The website failed to load, you can check the http://cefsharp.github.io/api/91.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_FrameLoadEndEventArgs_HttpStatusCode.htm
4. A navigation has occurred and the V8Context has been freed . If Load is called or the html document navigates internally you the frame for which FrameLoadEnd was called may no longer have a valid V8Context.

You can evaluate JavaScript directly against the frame to avoid the check. The [FrameLoadEndEventArgs.Frame](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/91.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_FrameLoadEndEventArgs_Frame.htm) property can be used to access the frame. You can then directly call [IFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/91.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IFrame_EvaluateScriptAsync.htm)

Comment: But the weird thing is that I was able to execute another JavaScript which is to set the overflow to hidden before this Script @amaitland

Comment: Execute the script directly against the frame. As I said this will  bypass the check which throws the exception. I can only speculate as to possible reasons as you haven't provided a complete example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example